# How do I databind text to my textbox from a seperate class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Okay so I am currently trying to bind some data to a textbox in my application and this is what it looks like.
I have a Page.xaml with a textbox on it (and some other things but we dont care about those because we want to bind data to the Textbox and nothing else)

And I have a class which is called Server, this class is responsible for starting the .jar file and some other minor things.
When it starts the process it starts a BAT file, you know, a cmd window.
And then I've made it to where it redirects the output so whatever gets printed to the cmd window we want to capture and append in the textbox on the PlayPage.xaml which is the page I mentioned earlier.

The issue I am having is that I want to databind whatever comes from the cmd window to my textbox, this is possible because I've done it before but it wasnt by using databinding.

So with other words. The text that gets sent to the cmd window I want that to be redirected to my textbox.

Here is a picture showing the text that gets printed to the cmd window (it keeps printing more over time)
[image]

Here is the structure of the project

[image]

Here is the XAML

```
<TextBox x:FieldModifier="public" Name="TbConsoleOutput" Background="#262626" Foreground="GreenYellow" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="141" Margin="10,33,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding Output}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="660"/>
```

Here is the class

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using CraftaServ.Pages;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace CraftaServ.Classes
{
    public class Server
    {
        private readonly PlayPage PlayPage;


        public int ProcessID;
        public Process ServerProcess = new Process();
        public string Output { get; set; }


        public void StartServer()
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Server File | *.jar";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                var IsStarted = false;
                var FilePath = Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);

                var StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", $"-Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.12.2.jar -o true");

                StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

                ServerProcess.StartInfo = StartInfo;
                ServerProcess.OutputDataReceived += ServerProcess_OutputDataReceived;
                ServerProcess.ErrorDataReceived += ServerProcess_ErrorDataReceived;

                ServerProcess.Start();
                ServerProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                ServerProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();


                ProcessID = ServerProcess.Id;


                IsStarted = true;
                while (IsStarted)
                    if (ServerProcess.HasExited)
                    {
                        IsStarted = false;
                        MessageBox.Show("Process has exited! Process ID: " + ProcessID);
                    }
            }
        }

        private void ServerProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Output = e.Data; });
            //I want to append e.Data to the textbox in on the PlayPage.xaml which is where the Textbox is located
        }

        private void ServerProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Output = e.Data; });
            //I want to append e.Data to the textbox in on the PlayPage.xaml which is where the Textbox is located
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implements the interface INotifyPropertyChanged in your Server class

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Then in your "Output" setter call the method 
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

Depending of the rest of your code you may need to set the datacontext of the view to the server class directly or to your xaml.cs class itself then change your Text databinding to the property Server.Output

Comment: I did not quite follow that, mind explaining that a bit more?

Comment: To have your databinding working you need several things : A valid datacontext (Where to find the binding you wrote in your xaml file) and data in your datacontext that inform the user interface when they're updated (By implementing the InotifyPropertyChanged interface and explicitely call this method when you set a property value that you want to be reflected in the user interface)

Comment: I didn't saw the  private readonly PlayPage PlayPage property at the top of your Server class.The link must be done in the other way too : your PlayPage must have somewhere a reference to the server class to access to the 'Output" property.